# Tomcat起動時に「以前のエラーのためにコンテキストの起動が失敗しました」というエラー

Tags: java, spring

SpringでMySQL(ver:8.0.11)を接続してDB処理を行いたいのですがTomcatを起動したときに「以前のエラーのためにコンテキストの起動が失敗しました」というエラーが下記のようにコンソールに表示されます。

```
警告: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt [水 7 04 00:05:17 GMT+09:00 2018]
重大: Context initialization failed [水 7 04 00:05:17 GMT+09:00 2018]
重大: クラス org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener のリスナインスタンスにコンテキスト初期化イベントを送信中の例外です [水 7 04 00:05:17 GMT+09:00 2018]
重大: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file [水 7 04 00:05:17 GMT+09:00 2018]
重大: 以前のエラーのためにコンテキストの起動が失敗しました [/SampleSpringTest] [水 7 04 00:05:17 GMT+09:00 2018]
```

eclipse上のDBViewerではちゃんと接続できてSQLが実行できることを確認はできています。どう対処すればよいのでしょうか。「pom.xml」には下記のような記述をしているのですがそこに原因があったりするのでしょうか。

●pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: mysqlのverを<version>5.1.38</version>に変えるとTomcat起動時のエラーはなくなりますがアプリケーションを実行したときに「HTTPステータス 500 - Could not get JDBC 」のエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: 切り分けていかないと原因はわかりませんが、TomcatからMysqlに接続できてないとそのようなエラーになると思います。

Answer (score 1):

コンソールの出力にある通り、

> One or more listeners failed to start.

リスナーを起動する際に何らかのエラーが発生しています。また、

> Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

とあるので、`$CATALINA_HOME/logs`（※）の中にあるログを確認してみて下さい。そこに出力されているエラーが何を意味するのか分からないようでしたら、質問を編集して追記して下さい。

※ログの出力先を変えているようでしたら、そちらを確認してみて下さい。

Comment: Tomcatのログファイルがなぜか出力されていないのでエラーの詳細がつかめていない状態です。eclipse上にMySQL8.0.11をインストールはしているのですがMySQLのmysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jarはeclipse上のどこかに配置しないといけないでしょうか。

Comment: [Tomcatのソースコード](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8fd5d6273099c504e1739080c07cf4d33cff89bf/java/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContext.java#L5110)（※正確にはリンク先のコードのバージョンは違いますが、実装はほぼ同じだと思います）を読むと、上記メッセージが出力されるときに何らかのエラーメッセージがTomcatのログに出力されるように見えます。原因はログを見ないと何とも言えないので、ログ出力の設定も見なおした方がいいかもしれませんね。